# Error when trying to expand an action in a flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, error, power-automate

I'm building a rather large workflow and it's gotten fairly unwieldy to edit in the browser. Refreshing the page takes a full minute, expanding a scope takes several clicks and 30 seconds, and now I can't even expand a full action. See the attached screen shot for the error message, I don't have any idea what it means. I googled it and found exactly 1 result which doesn't apply to me. Kinda stumped here. Should I break up the workflow? Is there a way around this? What exactly is the issue?[image]

Comment: Looks like a throttling issue. How many actions, that is data cards including variables, do you have in your flow? A 365 license can run only 2000 actions per 24 hours, so if you are running other flows with your account, it's possible that MS is throttling your account.

Comment: Yes, this most definitely is a throttling issue.  I have a couple of questions, since I have experienced this before:  Is The flow triggered by SharePoint or PowerApps?  What is the largest number of nested if-then loops in the Flow?  Also, are you using the Power Automate Free licensing or the non-Free licensing in your tenant?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like **throttling requests issue**.

All the users of **Microsoft Power Platform** have limits on the number of requests based on the **license** they are assigned. The following table defines the number of requests a user can make in a **24-hour** period:

[image]

More information, please refer to this article:

- [Requests limits and allocations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations)